# how to customize a blender file?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Can anyone guide me on where to look (ideally with some examples) how to programatically customize a blender file?

Specifically, for simplicity - I want to do this.

Programatically:

a) Add a text object

b) Rotate it 90 degrees on the x plane

c) Convert it to a mesh

d) "Center" the mesh it (so somehow figure out the text object width, and centers on origin)

e) Add a basic animation (keyframes)

Thanks!